# How to control quantity and increase

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, web-services

I'm using webservice to add product to basket here the code ;

```
[WebMethod]

    public void calistir(int urunid, string GirenIp)
    {
        using (Models.DermabonEntities db = new Models.DermabonEntities())
        {


            var productName = (from i in db.Product
                               where i.Id == urunid
                               select i.ProductName).FirstOrDefault();
            var productPrice = (from i in db.Product
                                where i.Id == urunid
                                select i.ProductPrice).FirstOrDefault();

            var productId = (from i in db.Product
                             where i.Id == urunid
                             select i.Id).FirstOrDefault();
            var productPic = (from i in db.Product
                              where i.Id == urunid
                              select i.ProductPicture).FirstOrDefault();

            var userIp = GirenIp;

            Basket create = new Basket();

            create.ProductName = productName;
            create.ProductId = productId;
            create.ProductPrice = productPrice;
            create.ProductPic = productPic;
            create.UserId = userIp;
            var qua = "2";
            create.ProductQuantity = Convert.ToInt32(qua);


            db.Basket.Add(create);
            db.SaveChanges();




        }

    }
```

Here I add quantity of product manually. But I want to control if there is same product increase quantity and if not make quantity 1.

I've tried something like this ;

```
var CountProduct= db.Basket.FirstOrDefault();
            if (CountProduct.ProductId == urunid)
            {
                CountProduct.ProductQuantity += Convert.ToInt32(adet);
                create.ProductQuantity = Convert.ToInt32(adet);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
```

GirenIp = sessionID which comes from ajax , urunId = ProductId which comes from ajax , adet means quantity.

Ajax ;

```
  function sepeteEkle(id) {

         var urunid = id;
         var GirenIp = $("#userId").val();
         $.ajax({
             dataType: "json",
             type: "POST",
             contentType: "application/json",
             url: "/Admin/WebService/Control.asmx/calistir",
             data: "{'urunid':'" + urunid + "','GirenIp':'" + GirenIp + "' }",
             success: function(){
                 $("#cartContent").load("MiniSepet.aspx #cartContent");
             },
             error: function () {
                 $("#cartContent").load("MiniSepet.aspx #cartContent");
             }
         });
         return false;
     }


     $(document).on('click', '.sepetat', function () {
         var nId = $(this).data("id")
         sepeteEkle(nId);
     });



sepetat= add to basket
```

basket table ;

```
 public partial class Basket
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ProductId { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> ProductPrice { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ProductQuantity { get; set; }
    public string ProductPic { get; set; }
}
```

}

Comment: I realize English may not be your first language, but please use `code` (not codes) for both the singular and plural. You don't say "codes" in English (at least not in the context of *source-code*, which it is short for) e.g. "this is my code", "here is some code" etc :)

Comment: According to your code, *you have only one basket for all users*... I am guessing that is not the case :) I will adjust code accordingly.

Comment: Yes I have one basket for all users Im creating session ID for every user and sending it to the basket.So I control basket with sessionID

Comment: OK. you will need to make some small changes to the answer below, but it shows a better pattern for lookup and modification of your objects. Use `Find` to get a single record based on primary key. Do not keep calling LINQ queries over and over for single properties (each one was a separate SQL request!).

Comment: +1 as the question is now complete (and you need 20 rep to use chat instead of dozens of comments!) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not want to run multiple LINQ queries on the same object, just to get several properties. That will cause SQL code to be run multiple times (4 times in your example). Just fetch the object once and use its properties.

You also want to clean things up a bit and use a simple pattern like this:

```
public void calistir(int urunid, string GirenIp) 
{
    using(Models.DermabonEntities db = new Models.DermabonEntities()) 
    {
        // Find the product by primary key
        var product = db.Product.Find(urunid);
        if (product != null) 
        {
            var productName = product.ProductName;
            var productPrice = product.ProductPrice;
            var productId = urunid;
            var productPic = product.ProductPicture;

            var userIp = GirenIp;

            // Get existing basket entry if any based on session/user id and product id
            Basket basket = dn.basket.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.UserId == userIp && x.ProductId == productId);
            if (basket == null) 
            {
                // basket does not already exist, so add new basket
                basket = new Basket() 
                {
                    // You can use property assignment with constructors
                    ProductName = productName,
                    ProductId = productId,
                    ProductPrice = productPrice,
                    ProductPic = productPic,
                    UserId = userIp,
                    ProductQuantity = 1      // Your initial quantity
                }
                db.Basket.Add(basket);
            } 
            else 
            {
                // Existing basket, just increase the quantity
                basket.ProductQuantity++;
            }
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Most of your temporary variables are not actually needed:

```
public void calistir(int urunid, string GirenIp) 
{
    using(Models.DermabonEntities db = new Models.DermabonEntities()) 
    {
        // Find the product by primary key
        var product = db.Product.Find(urunid);
        if (product != null) 
        {
            var userIp = GirenIp;

            // Get existing basket entry if any based on session/user id and product id
            Basket basket = dn.basket.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.UserId == userIp && x.ProductId == urunid);
            if (basket == null) 
            {
                // basket does not already exist, so add new basket
                basket = new Basket() 
                {
                    // You can use property assignment with constructors
                    ProductName = product.ProductName,
                    ProductId = product.ProductId,
                    ProductPrice = product.ProductPrice,
                    ProductPic = product.ProductPicture,
                    UserId = userIp,
                    ProductQuantity = 1      // Your initial quantity
                }
                db.Basket.Add(basket);
            } 
            else 
            {
                // Existing basket, just increase the quantity
                basket.ProductQuantity++;
            }
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```